# Pylint doesn't detect an undefined variable in an 'else' clause

Tags: python, pylint, pyflakes

I have the following python code

```
a = 2
if a == 1:
    b = 'blah'
    print b
else:
    print b
```

When I try to run it, I get a runtime error since 'b' is only defined in the 'if' clause, not the 'else'.

Pylint and Pyflakes both failed to detect this issue.

Is there any other way I can detect it without running the code?

Comment: im pretty sure pycharm  lints this sort of thing for me ... maybe not ... Ill check later

Comment: Pycharm was indeed able to detect this, but I'm trying to add a linter to an automated build process, so I don't know if can use it.

Comment: try pychecker maybe? I think thats what its called

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is detectable without running the code because in general, there may be more complex logic at work than your example. What about a loop that iterates this `if`-`else` clause multiple times, and for some reason you're sure that the first time around, `b` will definitely be assigned? A checker would need to be exactly as complex as the interpreter (and perform similar operations, probably including side effects) to know about all possible states of a program run. See the notion of static code checking.

Comment: Control flow analysis is [on the roadmap for astroid](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/issues/213) (the library behind pylint). While it surely won't detect a complex case like you describe, in the future it'll be able to analyze the simpler cases where it can infer the outcome of the condition (like in @freakazoid's example).